# Java - MaterialDialog - how to add clear button on edittext programmatically

Tags: java, android, material-dialog

I want to add programmatically cross button right side of edit text.
The idea is create a dialog like this one [How to add clear button to TextField Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927928/how-to-add-clear-button-to-textfield-widget). that problem is solved in Flutter, i?ve the same problem but in Java

```
            name = hint;
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()))
                .title("TITLE")
                .titleColorRes(R.color.textColorPrimary)
                .input(hint, hint, (dialog, input) -> {
                    SelectedFragment.this.name = input.toString();

                })
                .buttonsGravity(GravityEnum.END)
                .buttonRippleColorRes(R.color.colorAccent)
                .positiveText(R.string.confirm)
                .positiveColorRes(R.color.textColorPrimary)
                .onPositive((dialog, which) ->
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                            SelectedFragmen.this.type = type;
                                Intent data = new Intent();
                                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                                activity.finish();

                        }, 275)
                ).show();
    }));
```