# How to clear all different variables on a flutter screen using a button?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, variables

I am pretty new to flutter and want to know how can I clear all the input fields on a screen.
I am not using a form field so I can't use reset function. I got a reset button where I want when I click it reinitialise all input fields and refresh the screen.

These are my variables -

````
  bool _check2 = false;
  bool _check3 = false;
  bool _check4 = false;

  int taxYear = DateTime.now().year;
  TextEditingController taxDueController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? payoffDate;
  DateTime? filingTaxDate;
  bool? filingEx1;
  bool? filingEx2;
  DateTime? noticeDate;
  TextEditingController adjustmentTaxController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? installmentStartDate;
  DateTime? installmentEndDate;
  DateTime? levyDate;
  int? noOfPayment;
  DateTime? payment1Date;
  TextEditingController payAmount1Controller = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? payment2Date;
  TextEditingController payAmount2Controller = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? payment3Date;
  TextEditingController payAmount3Controller = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? payment4Date;
  TextEditingController payAmount4Controller = TextEditingController();
  bool detailedComputation = false;
  DateTime payoffDateV0 = DateTime.now();
  DateTime dateInNotice = DateTime.now();
  final int _startYear = 2010;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Stateful Widget and setState to update variables that are used in your UI.

This document will probably be helpful: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive

You can use setState in a stateful widget to update your field values to be null/empty. This will tell Flutter to re-build your form fields.

Something like this:

```
void resetButtonClicked() {
  setState(() {
     myVar = null;
     // clear other variables
  });
}
```

However, for the controllers, there is a clear method that you can use. See this answer:
[How to add clear button to TextField Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927928/how-to-add-clear-button-to-textfield-widget)